# Why isn't the following expect ... toThrowError logging anything in my terminal?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a helper that just throws an error:

```
export const checkPanoramaFormat = (panorama) => {
  if (!panorama.objectId) {
    throw new Error('panorama id is required')
  }
}
```

This is my test:

```
import {
  checkPanoramaFormat
} from '@/common/helpers'

describe('checkPanoramaFormat', () => {
  const panorama = { anotherProp: '1' }

  it('creates clone', () => {
    expect(checkPanoramaFormat(panorama)).toThrowError('hshshs')
  })
})
```

I expected the terminal to show me what was expected and what I got. But I got nothing. In fact, Jest isn't telling me anything:

[image]

Why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try instead:

```
expect(() => {
  checkPanoramaFormat(panorama)
}).toThrow('hshshs')
```

If you call the function immediately as the `expect` argument, it will throw the exception before the assertion. It is not inside a `try/catch` block. You should instead pass a function handler to `expect` to be called only on assertion. I enclosed it in an arrow function, but it can be called other forms such as:

```
expect(myFunc) // no arguments
expect(myFunc.bind(this, arg1, arg2)) // using .bind to set arguments for later calling
```

Comment: Documentation lays this out perfectly: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror

Comment: Some people put dummy assertion inside a try/catch, I'm not a fan of this method though. kinda: `try { expect(fn).toThrow() } catch { expect(true).equals(true) }`

Comment: @alex your assertion is wrong, you're not expecting the correct error message back.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
import {
  checkPanoramaFormat
} from '@/common/helpers'

describe('checkPanoramaFormat', () => {
  const panorama = { anotherProp: '1' }

  it('creates clone', () => {
    const result = () => checkPanoramaFormat(panorama)

    expect(result).toThrowError('panorama id is required')
  })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).